# Number of steps require to do a Git merge

Tags: git, git-extensions

I need a bit of advice on the merging my development branch to the master branch.
Also note that I'm using Git Extensions so try to avoid too much command line jargon if possible.

Say I've made 3 commits on the **dev** branch (and I still currently have it checked out, and the **mst** branch has 1 commit after from when I branched off.

```
dev:    1 ---> 2 ---> 3
       /
      /
mst: 0 --- X
```

Now I want to merge my **dev** branch into the **mst** branch BUT, I actually only want to merge commits 1 & 2.

My understanding is that I'll need to CHECKOUT **mst** (stash or make a temp commit beforehand for any in-progress work) and merge **mst** with commit 2.

```
dev:    1 ---> 2 ---> 3
       /        \
      /          \
mst: 0 --- X ---- 4
```

Now, commit 3 is *out of sync* so the next thing to do is to *re-sync* the **dev** branch.
To do this, I need to CHECKOUT **dev** and either merge **dev** with **mst** or rebase **dev** onto **mst**

ie.

```
dev:     1 ---> 2 ---> 3 --- 5
        /        \          /
       /          \   ------
      /            \ /
mst: 0 ---- X ----- 4
```

or

```
dev:    1 ---> 2     5
       /        \   /
      /          \ /
mst: 0 --- X ---- 4
```

The main issue that doesn't sit well with the other developers is that merging might become a huge time waster because

1. you need to "save" your current work, then checkout **mst** then go back to checkout **dev**  (we're using VB6, so we also need to close and reopen VB6 to reload the files because of potential merge conflicts and VB6 doesn't recognise files that have been modified externally)
2. the double merge process (one to *update* **mst** and the other to *re-sync* **dev**)

Also, I've had some reliability issues with stash (sometimes stash pop prevents me from popping), which is why I suggest to my fellow developers to just make a temp commit (after commit 3), then do a mixed reset at the end.

We're a small company so getting things out as fast as possible is a priority (but we can't push out everything because some things be held back).
Is this many steps actually required, or is there a faster way?

Comment: Two suggestions.  If you want fast, you should really do this from command line.  It is a lot faster to type `git merge mst` than clicking around the UI.  Also, if you are just pulling changes from the *master* branch into your *dev* branch, you should use `rebase` to help keep your history a bit cleaner.  So your workflow would be `git stash, git rebase mst, git stash pop`.  The other benefit of using `rebase` is that merging your changes into *mst* will be really easy (because you will have already fixed all the merge conflicts on your branch).

Comment: Thinking about it some more, if you want to bring commits 1 and 2 into *mst* but not 3, you should really put them on different branches so each branch corresponds to a feature or a development effort.  Branches are quick to create and a good way to keep different development efforts from mixing before they are ready.

Comment: That can be fixed pretty quickly too though.  `git branch commit3, git checkout dev, git reset --hard [sha of commit2]`.  You will now have 3 branches: *mst*, *dev* with commits 1 and 2, and *commit3* with commit 3.  Finally `git rebase --onto mst dev commit3` should make the branch *commit3* come off of *mst* instead of *dev*.  The [documentation](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing) for rebase has a much better explanation with charts and everything.  By the way, you want me to put these comments together into an answer?

Comment: This issue isn't so much about speed on GUI vs command line, it's more an issue of not disrupting what you're working on right now in order to push the commits that do need to be pushed publically.
Sadly, I know exactly what you're saying, but what I was looking for is some magical process that would somehow minimize the amount of time spent having to close the VB6 editor, merge, then re-sync (wishful thinking, I know).
Unfortunately the other developers are still in the old SourceSafe mindset, and convinced this whole process is too slow (for a one line fix, there is a lot of steps involved).

Comment: Yeah, in that sense Visual Studio 2010 (and better in 2012) are pretty forgiving about files and projects switching underneath them and just reloading them obediently.

Comment: Your best bet at convincing other developers is getting really good at doing it yourself, and using branches to keep all of your work items separate.  Then when you are comfortable and can practically execute those commands in your sleep (even from command line), casually show off to your co-workers how easy it is, or how much time it saved you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git requires use of a working directory and index during a merge operation because you'll need them to resolve any merge conflicts that arise.

If you need to keep your working directory in a dirty state while you do the merge, then you can create a cloned repository using your primary local repository as the origin. Then do all your merging in your clone, and fetch the changes back into your primary repository

You can use Git Extensions to do the clone, or you can use a command such as:

```
cd C:\Users\Basewq\Code
git clone MyProject MyProjectForMerging
```

Then, when you wanted to do a merge without disrupting your working directory, pull changes from MyProject into MyProjectForMerging, do the merge, then fetch the commits back into MyProject (warning: don't push changes into MyProject, always fetch/pull). Again, you can use Git Extensions, or you can use the command line:

```
cd C:\Users\Basewq\Code\MyProjectForMerging
git checkout mst
git pull
git merge dev
```

And to bring the changes back in to your primary repository:

```
cd ..\MyProject
git fetch ..\MyProjectForMerging
```

Now the commits will be in the MyProject repository, ready to be pushed back to origin or wherever. You could also push from MyProjectForMerging into any other remotes, if you wanted.

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer as it does minimise the disruption, though for it's definitely for intermediate/advanced Git users due to the extra "clean up" required after working on the secondary working directory. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Use Branches**

As suggested in the comments, the easiest way to do this is to create a new branch after the second commit (as in, just before you start working on the changes for commit #3).

If you do it like this, you will have a clean merge-point, no matter what further work you do.

Your workflow seems to be influenced by prior experience with centralized vcs. Just because there's a branch 'master' (mst) or 'develop' (dev) on your authorative repo doesn't mean you have to call them the same, or that there needs to be a one-to-one correspondence.

I feel that in git, it's often easier to create short-lived branches (with whatever name), and then simply merge the appropriate branches when pushing to your public or the authorative repo.

Answer (score 0):

What is the tool you are using? I use Mac client for github:

http://mac.github.com/.

Branching, merging, changing between branches are just 30sec operations for me with this excellent tool. But of course you work on a quite a high abstraction level, but for day-today use thats is just what I need.

It has a windows varient too, but I haven't used and do not know if any limitation exists there:

http://windows.github.com/

---

Mainly there are 3 levels of source management tools:

1) VSS style blocked checkouts: This is the historical way of doing it.. If you have one developer or developers who do not work on same files simultaneously this could work for you.

2) SVN style non blocking checkouts: All developers work on a central repo, but they may work on the same file simultaneously. If there are conflicts, those need to be resolved before committing (update/resolve before commit)

3) Git style distributed SCM: This brings best value when you have developers who do own independent development with their local repos for longer periods of time. Once they are satisfied with the outcome, they may decide to publish their changes to the parent repo. Mostly used for open source development.

You need to pick the best model that work for your development style. For most of the commercial organizations with a closely working team, SVN model works quite good. If you have more complicated development team, Git may help you to deal with it.

Comment: I'm using Git Extensions (it's a Windows GUI for Git), and merge with KDiff3.

It's the whole "clean-up" operation that the other developers don't like which is potentially a time waster that didn't exist before (we were using SourceSafe, ie. Check-out/block -> Edit -> Check-in/unblock).

It really disrupts you if you're in the middle of something, and in order to push some of your completed work, you need to save your work in-progress, do a whole bunch of "clean-up" to push back to the public repo, then re-sync your work in-progress.

Is this just the way of life now?

Comment: edited the answer to describe different levels of SCM tools. Each level brings more power as well as added complexity.

Comment: You're right, each level of power brings in more complexity. The answer I was hopelessly looking for is some way to reduce the complexity on doing the simplest things (eg. one line fix), but it seems this is the cost of having all this power. It's been a while since I last used SVN, but I think the issue I'm raising would still happen in SVN. It will take some time to convince the other developers why all these extra steps are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Git requires use of a working directory and index during a merge operation because you'll need them to resolve any merge conflicts that arise.

If you need to keep your working directory in a dirty state while you do the merge, then you can tell Git to temporarily use an alternative working directory and index. However, this requires the command line and might be confusing.

The goal is to create a temporary index file and a temporary working directory. Point Git to them, do the merge, then restore the normal index and working directory.

```
:: Create a temporary working directory, but use my normal repository

mkdir C:\Temp\MyProject
set GIT_DIR=C:\Users\Basewq\Code\MyProject  -- (path to my normal repo)
set GIT_INDEX_FILE=C:\Temp\index
set GIT_WORK_TREE=C:\Temp\MyProject

:: Now do the merge in C:\Temp\MyProject

git checkout mst
git merge dev

:: Now put everything back

set GIT_DIR=
set GIT_INDEX_FILE=
set GIT_WORK_TREE=
del C:\Temp\index
rd /q /s C:\Temp\MyProject
```